# Find the logarithm of a number in Scala

Tags: scala

How do you find the base y logarithm  of a number x in Scala? I have searched the scala.math library and I can't find a way. It seems to have only log10(x) and ln(x).

Comment: For completeness, there is also log1p(x), which returns the natural log of 1+x.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a maths question :)

```
log<base y>(x) == log10(x)/log10(y) == ln(x)/ln(y)
```

Random link from the web that explains this:

http://www.purplemath.com/modules/logrules5.htm

Comment: There isn't a function in the library to do this? I thought that I wouldn't have to compute it by myself. Although that I already know how to do it mathematically I would prefer for an already implemented function.

Comment: I do remember having to do this in java long time ago (10 years+!!) and having to resort to this technique. Could have changed.

Comment: It is a great way and I will use it as I haven't find another one. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

For convenience, you can use a lambda function, e.g.,

```
scala> val log2 = (x: Double) => log10(x)/log10(2.0)
log2: Double => Double = <function1>

scala> log2(2)
res0: Double = 1.0
```